# Show pop up on same viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, popup

I have 2 view controller (A,B). In A viewcontroller I have one button.When that button pressed .My B viewcontroller should show up like pop up on same viewcontroller (A).with background of 'A' viewcontroller.Tat should like this image [This image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzlCAVXRsIPcNWUxODM2MDAtNDE3OS00ZTc4LTk5N2MtZDA3NjFlM2IzNmZk/view?ddrp=1&pli=1&hl=en_US#).I too follow some suggestion gave in stackoverflow.But its seems not work [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509392/best-method-to-show-a-popup-transparent-window-on-iphone) [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411383/xcode-how-to-create-a-popup-view-controller-that-appears-in-another-view-contro/#) .Some one please suggest me How to do this.I dont need some alert message and all.I need to work like my above image link(This image) Also in my pop up viewcontroller where ever i touch it should move again to 'A' Viewcontroller

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can popup your view controller above your current view controller same as you describe in your image. Please refer below link for your popup view...
https://github.com/evnaz/ENPopUp

Comment: i have seen this project.its work well.but my first viewcontroller background make fully blur.i need to show slight blur alone.I have changed the values also.but its not seems work well for background

Comment: As you can see in that there is JWBlurView.h & JWBlurView.m file. You can change with in it and get output according to your requirement.

Comment: yes i changed there only.but all method are based on blur.i too change some values.but its not work.this is my first ios app.i am very beginner in it